# What are the pros and cons of Playwright-test VS jest-playwright-preset

Tags: ts-jest, playwright

If one were to start a brand new project and we want to use Playwright with TypeScript for front-end testing, would you recommend we use Playwright-test or Jest-Playwright-preset as the test runner? Please indicate why you would pick one over the other. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend Playwright Test, because

- it works without other external dependencies
- has support for TypeScript out of the box
- has multi-project support with different browser configurations
- Supports trace-viewer, video, and screenshot creation out of the box via the config.
- Applies context per test best practice to have them isolated and self contained

For more references see here: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-intro